# Polar Revolution Solid in R

Tags: r, 3d, rotation, polar-coordinates

I'm trying to do a polar revolution solid in R, but I can´t found nothing working in R 3.0.2
For example I need do a revolution solid of this function around the x axis, before had a package for it called  parametric3d, but it is only for cartesian.
what do you advise me?

Example 2D.

```
library(plotrix)
b=seq(0,359,by=1)
c=(b)*pi/180  
a=(cos(c))^2*sin(c)
polar.plot(a,b,main="Test Polar Plot",lwd=2,line.col=4,rp.type="p")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I'm solve this problem with RGL, thanks you a lot for your help.
The final code is:

```
#####  2D #####

library(plotrix)
grad=seq(0,359,by=1)
rad=grad*pi/180  # degrees to radian
func=(cos(rad))^2*sin(rad)
func=abs(func)   # to plot negative numbers
polar.plot(func,grad,rp.type="p",radial.lim=c(0,1),
lwd=2,line.col=4,main="Polar Plot")

#####  3D #####

### Polar to Cartesians ###

x=func*cos(rad)
y=func*sin(rad)
y=abs(y)  # eliminate symmetrics ones (only y>=0)
library(rgl)
shade3d(turn3d(x, y), col = "green")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to do with the solid?  Just plot it? or something else?

If you just want to plot it then here are some options:

Convert the polar coordinates to Cartesian and use the package you did before.

Look at the rgl package for representing solids in 3d through R (probably need to convert to Cartesian coords).

Use the gnuplot program instead of R.